# How to get collection name in Solr QueryParserPlugin

Tags: java, solr

I am writting my own Query Parser for Solr, and I need to know collection name. How can I do?

The plugin params are ofc:

```
public QParser(String qstr, SolrParams localParams, SolrParams params, SolrQueryRequest req) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For SolrCloud mode, use:

```
req.getCore().getCoreDescriptor().getCollectionName()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the following ...

[req](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/request/SolrQueryRequest.html).[getCore()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/request/SolrQueryRequest.html#getCore%28%29).[getName()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/core/SolrCore.html#getName%28%29)

SolrQueryRequest -> Core -> Name

Comment: I did, but if I have replication/sharding it will return something like **test_shard2_replica2**. This way I access core, but can I get Solr Collection object?